# Can I install a disk on ps4 instead of downloading the game data?

Tags: ps4

I bought a digital game (Rainbow Six) today and I must download the data from play station network. My friend owns that game on a disk. Could I install his game on my ps4 istead of downloading the data from psn?

Comment: How about trying and then letting us know? :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this wont work. If you got the BluRay just the important things get installed in background for faster access while the whole game get installed if you download it from psn.

Comment: i dont think thats gonna work too . but i let you know

Comment: @Nitro.de i have another question : when i sign up in psn the online id is the screen name in multiplayer (online) ? or my screen name is my profile name in the console ?

Comment: @John - PSN = online. Your local profile name is what you select as soon as the PS4 is turned on.

Comment: Also, after looking online, the disk install and store download seem to be pretty close in size... So it's probably not even worth trying. (you can double-check the store download against what his case says). Developers do what they can to keep the size down, so I'd be surprised if there was some kind of "hack" like this that worked.

Comment: Do not edit your existing questions to ask new ones just because this site is limiting you. If you can't ask for 5 days, there's a reason behind that...

Answer (score 1):

No it won't work. You have two versions of the game: digital and physical. Your friend has physical and doesn't need to authenticate through Sony's servers; digital versions do.

Answer (score -3):

It won't work. I own Bloodborne digitally and physically, but when I want to use the digital version, I need to delete the whole game just to redownload it.